# Spark wholeTextFiles takes file/folder names with a colon (:) as path

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm processing a lot of data with Spark (application is written in Python 3.4), some of the files and folders have a colon `:` in their name, such as `http:` (yes, that's a folder name) or `File:a_picture.jpg`. The last one causes the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: File:a_picture.jpg
```

It's part of an RDD created with sc.wholeTextFiles(). The `http:` one caused a similar error, expecting a protocol of some sort.

I have no control over how this data is created. I am able to rename all the files/folders before I launch my Spark application; however I have to run my application, fix any errors that come up, try again... you get the picture. I would like to keep the original names as well.

Is there a way I can tell Spark to not try to convert the file/folder names to paths or some protocols and take them literally?

Comment: Nothing will make it a valid URI but if you can rename just use percent encoding to generate valid names.

Comment: So I basically should replace every colon in file and folder names with %, correct? Guess I'll do that if there is no way around it.

Comment: Not exactly. You can use [`urllib.parse.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) to generate valid names though it would be still be better to fix this upstream. More about [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).